# Why does Django raise "KeyError"?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am currently trying to implement pagination to my Django web app. However, when I try to use template tags from the [library](https://github.com/jmcclell/django-bootstrap-pagination), Django raises a key error. To be specific:

```
KeyError
KeyError: 'request'
```

Here is my settings.py:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from os.path import dirname, join, exists
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: join(BASE_DIR, "directory")
BASE_DIR = dirname(dirname(dirname(__file__)))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_ROOT = join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

# Use Django templates using the new Django 1.8 TEMPLATES settings
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            # insert more TEMPLATE_DIRS here
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Use 12factor inspired environment variables or from a file
import environ
env = environ.Env()

# Ideally move env file should be outside the git repo
# i.e. BASE_DIR.parent.parent
env_file = join(dirname(__file__), 'local.env')
if exists(env_file):
    environ.Env.read_env(str(env_file))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'authtools',
    'crispy_forms',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'geoposition',
    'bootstrap_pagination',

    'profiles',
    'accounts',
    'clients',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'saas.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'saas.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Crispy Form Theme - Bootstrap 3
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

# For Bootstrap 3, change error alert to 'danger'
from django.contrib import messages
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger'
}

# Authentication Settings
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authtools.User'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy("profiles:show_self")
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy("accounts:login")

THUMBNAIL_EXTENSION = 'png'     # Or any extn for your thumbnails
```

The template-tag I am trying to run is:

```
{% block pagination %}
    {% bootstrap_paginate page_obj range=10 show_prev_next="false" show_first_last="true" %}
{% endblock %}
```

What to do?

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: Does adding `django.template.context_processors.request` to your 'context_processors' help?

Comment: I am using Django 1.9 - and Alex Morozov, your solution worked, thx!

Comment: Great! Please mark the question as accepted so the others know they can rely on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `bootstrap_paginate` template tag [expects](https://github.com/jmcclell/django-bootstrap-pagination/blob/master/bootstrap_pagination/templatetags/bootstrap_pagination.py#L83) your template context to contain the `request` variable. Make it available by changing your `context_processors` to:

```
'context_processors': [
    # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
    # list if you haven't customized them:
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
    'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.template.context_processors.media',
    'django.template.context_processors.static',
    'django.template.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.request', # <-- Here we add the request
],
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have imported

```py
import django_heroku
```

Then put this:

```py
django_heroku.settings(local())
```

in the end of your **settings.py** file